# Error: Illegal String Offset in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i have been steadily developing my website until i got this error:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'user_post' in C:\xampp\xxxxxx\xxxx.php on line 15
```

I have been at it for three days now i still don't know what is causing this, this is the first time i have encountered this error so i do not really know how to solve and would really appreciate some help on this.

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
  $db = new mysqli("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxx");
  if($db->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
  }

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM page_posts";
  $post_arr = array();
  $post_arr = $db->query($sql);
  $post_rows = $post_arr->fetch_array()

  foreach($post_rows as $row)
  {
    echo $row['user_post'];
  }
?>
```

I use mysql and the datatype for that column is 'text'.

This is the table structure:

```
post_id    int
user_id    int
post_title int
user_post  text
post_date  datetime
post_page  varchar(32)
```

There are other columns but i have omitted them since they have nothing to do with the result.

This is the vardump result:

```
array(24) { [0]=> string(1) "3" ["post_id"]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "0" ["user_id"]=> string(1) "0" [2]=> string(13) "My First Post" ["post_title"]=> string(13) "My First Post" [3]=> string(329) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tincidunt neque in erat vestibulum, sed gravida odio venenatis. Nam ut nunc libero. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus volutpat ultricies enim. Nullam luctus odio urna, vitae posuere justo semper in." ["user_post"]=> string(329) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tincidunt neque in erat vestibulum, sed gravida odio venenatis. Nam ut nunc libero. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus volutpat ultricies enim. Nullam luctus odio urna, vitae posuere justo semper in." [4]=> string(19) "2013-11-22 00:00:00" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2013-11-22 00:00:00" [5]=> string(12) "Post-an-idea" ["post_page"]=> string(12) "Post-an-idea" [6]=> NULL ["additional_details"]=> NULL [7]=> string(1) "0" ["up_votes"]=> string(1) "0" [8]=> string(1) "0" ["down_votes"]=> string(1) "0" [9]=> NULL ["voted_users"]=> NULL [10]=> string(1) "1" ["is_valid"]=> string(1) "1" [11]=> string(6) "active" ["post_status"]=> string(6) "active" }
```

Comment: You dont have column "user_post" in your page_posts table.

Comment: Oh but i do, i have already double checked that.

Comment: Provide table structure please, as well as let us know which line is line 15, is it **$row['user_post']** because we can guess, but knowing helps

Comment: `mysqli::fetch_assoc` fetches a *single row*. Your `foreach` iterates over the fields in that row.

Comment: `var_dump($row)` to see what you're trying to treat as an array here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should iterate over the rows and not the colums of the same row.

```
<?php
  $db = new mysqli("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxx");
  if($db->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
  }

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM page_posts";
  $post_arr = array();
  $post_arr = $db->query($sql);

  while ($row = $post_arr->fetch_assoc())
  {
    echo $row['user_post'];
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's very late for the reply but still i would like to share this..
as you are using

> foreach() loop

therefore

> $post_rows must be an array. you are using it as variable.

so just use the following code

> $post_arr[] = $db->query($sql);
>   $post_rows[] = $post_arr->fetch_array();

everything else is perfect.